# how to use google+ hangout api for chat only

Tags: javascript, html, google-api

I`m creating page
and I need to add hangout button with functionality
to connect to my hangout and start chatting automaticaly on click

this is my code

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<div id="hangout" class="g-hangout" data-render="createhangout" data-invites="[{ id : 'bardavelidzemaia@gmail.com', invite_type : 'EMAIL' }]"></div>
```

but it is only calling...

how can I do this?

P.S.
Also I have created app_key
but I do not understand how to use this and when I need this key...

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to access chat from the Hangouts API. Take a look at the [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=29), star it if you want updates. For alternatives, check out Twilio or Pilvo.

Comment: thank you. I stared this issue. but can you understand me how to use app key and when I need this?